# Операторы или Циклы?

Tags: java, терминология, операторы

В книгах вижу часто вот такое: оператор if, оператор switch и тд.
Так же вижу слова аля: в этом цикле if или в этом цикле for работает так и вот так.

Как я понял: 
Оператор if 
Оператор while 
Оператор for 
Оператор switch

А вот циклы:

```
  if (true) {
        System.out.println("Правда");
   } else {
        System.out.println("Ложь");
   }



 int a = 0;
   while(a < 10){
       System.out.println(a);
       a++;
   }




for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   System.out.println("Hello " + i);
 }



int a = 5;
        switch (a) {
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Вася");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Петя");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Саша");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Леонид");
                break;
        }
```

Правильно? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Кажется всё что вы написали правильно (но это не точно :) )

Comment: `if` и `switch` это не циклы. `for` и `while` - циклы.

Comment: If и Switch - вот даже близко не циклы. И если кто-то написАл *в этом цикле if*, то он [skipped], и пусть этот косяк останется на его совести. А терминоголически - циклом называют как соответствующий оператор (тут скорее говорят о структуре программы), так и оператор вместе со всеми входящими в него операторами (а тут - уже о конкретной реализации).

Comment: @Akina, а почему if и switch не циклы и как вообще различить какой оператор, а какой цикл?

Comment: @Akina текст здесь выдран из контекста, там же может быть написано что "в этом цикле (оператор) if (проверяет что-либо)". А автор вопроса посчитал что "цикл if" единое сочетание, хотя на самом деле нет.

Comment: Циклы - это тоже операторы. for и while - операторы циклов, if и switch - условные операторы.

Comment: *а почему if и switch не циклы* Цикл предполагает, что его тело выполняется несколько раз (в том числе, возможно, один раз или даже ни одного раза) в зависимости от условия завершения либо повторения этого цикла. If и Switch - выполнился один раз и поскакал дальше. А For и While - будет повторяться, пока не будет достигнуто условие завершения.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо всем!

Comment: Ещё можно сказать, что в "цикле" есть изменяющийся счётчик, а в "условии" такой счётчик отсутствует.

Comment: @ИгорьГор *в "цикле" есть изменяющийся счётчик* Вовсе необязательно. `for (;;) {...; if (...) break; ...}`

Comment: @u_mulder *текст здесь выдран из контекста* Ну тогда на совести автора останется неаккуратность формулировок и двусмысленность фразы, которая может быть понята неверно.

Comment: Все здесь операторы. Циклы Вы самостоятельно строите с помощью операторов. Зациклить можно, что угодно и чем угодно. Рекурсия созданая с помощью оператора 'return' - тоже цикл. Другое дело, что операторы for, while do - созданны именно для построения циклов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while`, `do...while`, `for` - это циклы/[операторы цикла](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0_for,_while,_do_..._while).

`if`, `if-else`, `if-else-if`, `switch` - это [операторы принятия решения](http://proglang.su/java/decision-making-operators)(условные операторы). Так же есть условный оператор [`?:`](http://proglang.su/java/operators#ternarnyy-operator-ili-uslovnyy-operator).

Есть еще другие [операторы](http://proglang.su/java/operators) - `=`, `==`, `+=`, `&&`, `&` и т.д.

P.S. Конкретно для вашего вопроса: всё выше операторы, но не все операторы циклы.

Answer (score 4):

Оператор - ключевое **слово** (или символ) языка (программирования), имеющее определенное значение.

Цикл - **часть кода** программы, выполняющаяся несколько раз по кругу (хотя в некоторых случаях цикл может выполниться и один раз).

Answer (score 2):

Все перечисленное - управляющие конструкции.

Операторы 
`if (условие) {блок кода если условие истинно} else {блок кода если условие не истинно}`
обеспечивают простое ветвление, т.е. выполнение определенного блока кода при выполнении или не выполнении условия. 
Оператор `Switch` обеспечивает более сложное ветвление в зависимости от значения передаваемого параметра. 

Операторы `for, while, do...while` - это циклы, они обеспечивают ветвление с повторным использованием блока кода.

 
То что в java и условных операторов и операторов циклов несколько видов - это [синтаксический сахар](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80). Можно получить функционал `Switch` используя только `If`. Такая же ситуация с циклами.

```
for ( ; true; ) {блок кода}   // бесконечный цикл на for
while (true)    {блок кода}   // бесконечный цикл на while
```

Что использовать - зависит от конкретной ситуации и личных предпочтений.